# Terraform file for AWS S3 bucket keeps getting Error: Invalid provider configuration

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Edit: I've modified the question to show the entire main.tf file, now.

I have a Terraform file that is supposed to create an AWS S3 bucket, but one of the errors I keep getting every time I run `terraform plan` is this:

```
│ Error: Invalid provider configuration
│ Provider "registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws" requires explicit configuration. Add a provider block to the root module and configure the provider's required arguments as described in the provider documentation.
```

The main.tf file:

```
terraform {
    backend  "s3" {
    region         = "us-east-1"
    bucket         = "bucketname"
    key            = "path/terraform.tfstate" 
    dynamodb_table = "tf-state-lock" 
    access_key = "<access_key>"
    secret_key = "<secret_key"
    }

    required_providers {
      aws = {
        version = " ~> 3.0"
        source = "registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws"
      }
    }

} 

provider "aws" {
  alias  = "east" 
  region = "us-east-1"
  access_key = "access_key"
  secret_key = "secret_key"
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket" "tf-remote-state" {
  bucket = "bucketname" 

  versioning {
    enabled = true
  }

  lifecycle {
    prevent_destroy = true
  }
}

resource "aws_dynamodb_table" "dynamodb-tf-state-lock" {
  name            = "tf-state-lock" 
  hash_key        = "LockID"
  read_capacity   = 20
  write_capacity = 20

  attribute {
    name = "LockID"
    type = "S"
  }

  tags = {
    name = "state lock"
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the actual main.tf where you use this code? You just provided out of context snipets of code.

Comment: You don't need to specify the full URL when using providers hosted on the Terraform registry: drop the `registry.terraform.io` from the `source`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are using `alias` [1] in the `provider` block, the way resources are currently set up will cause Terraform to expect the un-aliased `provider` block to exist for the resources you want to create:

> By default, resources use a default provider configuration (one without an alias argument) inferred from the first word of the resource type name.

In other words, since you are not specifying the name of the aliased provider in the two resource blocks (for S3 and DynamoDB), Terraform wants to use the un-aliased provider configuration by default. As you don't have the provider block without `alias`, probably the easiest way to fix it is by adding the following to both resource blocks [2]:

```
provider = aws.east
```

The whole blocks would then look like this:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "tf-remote-state" {
  provider = aws.east
  bucket   = "bucketname" 

  versioning {
    enabled = true
  }

  lifecycle {
    prevent_destroy = true
  }
}

resource "aws_dynamodb_table" "dynamodb-tf-state-lock" {
  provider        = aws.east
  name            = "tf-state-lock" 
  hash_key        = "LockID"
  read_capacity   = 20
  write_capacity = 20

  attribute {
    name = "LockID"
    type = "S"
  }

  tags = {
    name = "state lock"
  }
}
```

However, if there are not any special reasons to use aliases (i.e., resources will be created in one region anyway), setting just the `region` (as you already did) would do the trick as well. If you do not want to use the alias, just drop the `alias = "east"` from the `provider` block and then you will not have to change anything in the resource blocks and the code will work as is.

---

[1] https://www.terraform.io/language/providers/configuration#alias-multiple-provider-configurations

[2] https://www.terraform.io/language/providers/configuration#selecting-alternate-provider-configurations

Answer (score 0):

I came from Google looking for

> Provider "registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws" requires explicit configuration.

This is how it's fixed: either you add this line to your `main.tf`:

```
provider "aws" {
  region = "eu-central-1"
}
```

or you define an environment variable:

```
AWS_REGION=eu-central-1
```